# SQL - Order/Delivery manipulation

Tags: sql, teradata

Figured this out in excel - just need to convert it to SQL - thought I would write this here in case anyone has looked at this and started to reply.

I'm currently looking at outstanding orders and future estimated deliveries for a range of products where there can be multiple orders and deliveries.  I have a large table — see image:

[image]

I have no reputation so unable to paste an image in here and I'm unable to draw it out using spaces,

A positive in the Quantity column represents a reserved order from a priority area that has first pick when any future order comes in.  Similarly a negative represents a delivery (For example if we look at product A;

**Week 1** – There is a priority order for 60.

**Week 2** – 40 are delivered meaning 40 are allocated to the 60 in priority order week 1 (still 20 outstanding).

**Week 3** – A New Priority order takes effect for 20 (combining with the 20 outstanding from Week 2 to create 40)

**Week 3** – at the same time in week 3 an order comes in for 50 – this can satisfy the current outstanding request for 40 leaving 10 left over

**Week 5** – A new priority order take effect for 20, taking the 10 remaining and creating an outstanding order of 10.

I’ve been looking for a way to nicely look at the effect of the priority orders such that the estimated quantity and therefore cost can be seen. i.e. for product A

**Week 1** - Initial Demand for 60  - can be ignored as nothing delivered

**Week 2** - 40 delivered       - 40 at cost

**Week 3** - 40 delivered       - 40 at cost

**Week 5** – 10 delivered       - 10 at cost

I think there may be an easy solution but having been looking at it for a while now I can’t see the wood from the trees.   I think there is an issue with when a large enough order comes in and there is sufficient quantity to cover the priority order yet the remaining has effectively been ‘reserved’ by the priority department and needs to be ‘rolled over’.
Any help or prompts much appreciated

Comment: Figured this out in excel - just need to convert it to SQL - thought I would write this as a comment here in case anyone has looked at this and started to reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first read your question it sounded like a stock-inventory problem, but based on your example data it seems to be a simple cumulative sum (at least for the first part):

```
SELECT
   product, week, quantity,
   SUM(quantity) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY product
         ORDER BY week
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS "cumulative quantity"
FROM tab
```

Regarding the second part I'm not shure what you expect as result, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Hi dnoeth, thank you for your comment - I was using something similar to what you have posted to get the 4th column.  I managed to get the result with a big case statement with nested statements inside - It is probably not very efficient but it manages to produce the results I needed.